# I can't trigger Wicket onchange event

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, automation, wicket

I am trying to automate the filling of three dropdown selection elements with a chrome extension. I can change the value of the first dropdown but that does not trigger the wicket that is in the onchange event. The wicket is supposed to load the second and third dropdown based on the first selection. What am I  missing here.

Can change the value of the first selection with

```
( "select:first-of-type" ).val( "2" );
```

Tried triggering the on change with,

```
$( "select:first-of-type" ).change();
$( "select:first-of-type" ).trigger('change');
$( "select:first-of-type" ).triggerHandler('change');
$( "select:first-of-type" ).trigger('onchange');
$( "select:first-of-type" ).triggerHandler('onchange');
```

etc etc none of these populate the second and third selects.

```
<div id="new-criteria">
<select name="tabContent:contentPanel:searchCriteriaPanel:newSearchCriteria:searchFie 
ldDropDown" id="id62a9" onchange="if (function(){return 
Wicket.$(&#039;id62a9&#039;) != null;}.bind(this)()) { 
Wicket.showIncrementally(&#039;veil&#039;);}var 
wcall=wicketAjaxPost(&#039;https://www.example.com?1343- 
2.IBehaviorListener.0-tabContent-contentPanel-searchCriteriaPanel- 
newSearchCriteria-searchFieldDropDown&#039;, 
wicketSerialize(Wicket.$(&#039;id62a9&#039;)),function() { 
;Wicket.hideIncrementally(&#039;veil&#039;);}.bind(this),function() { 
;Wicket.hideIncrementally(&#039;veil&#039;);}.bind(this), function() {if 
(!function() {return Wicket.$(&#039;id62a9&#039;) != null;}.bind(this)()) 
{Wicket.hideIncrementally(&#039;veil&#039;);}return 
Wicket.$(&#039;id62a9&#039;) != null;}.bind(this));">
<option selected="selected" value="">Choose One</option>
<option value="0">Opperation</option>
<option value="1">Selection</option>
<option value="2">Category</option>

</select>
<select name="tabContent:contentPanel:searchCriteriaPanel:newSearchCriteria:operatorDropDown" disabled="disabled">
<option selected="selected" value="">Choose One</option>
</select>
<span class="value">
<input type="text" value="" name="tabContent:contentPanel:searchCriteriaPanel:newSearchCriteria:value:valueField"     disabled="disabled"/>
    </span>
```

Changes the first value but does not populate the other 2

Comment: Use a pure DOM event: $('select:first-of-type')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true}))

Comment: No luck just refreshes page

Answer (score 0):

I had some bad expercience with `change` events as well in the past. I decided to roll my on custom event and trigger that.

So:

```
$('.myelement').trigger('customevent')
```

And in `Wicket`

```
this.add(new AjaxEventBehavior('customevent') {...  } )...
```

You can still decide to trigger `change` on your DOM if you listen to the `change` in JS, just make sure to trigger the `customevent` from that handler as well.